# Print int in hexadecimal format(0x11 not 0011)

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, hex

As the title suggests how do i print 17 in the hexadecimal format(0x11).
I have tried `printf("%04x",number);` but it prints the number as 0011(correct but not what i want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this its clean and simple.

Hexadecimal -> `printf("%#x",17);`

Octal       -> `printf("%#o",17)`;

More about `#` . Here's the link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 2):

Use the following instead:

```
printf("0x%x", number);
```

Comment: I have already tried this...i thought there was some format string paramter to do that but i guess there isn't..thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? `printf("0x%02x",number);`